# Triggered brakepoint without having any

Tags: visual-studio-2010

```
 MyProject has triggered breakpoint
```

without any brakepoints in my project (i have made sure using Debug/Delete all BP)

I do not really post some code, because project is really big and it is also impossible to make some minimal sample.

Where sould I look when getting this error?

TY

Comment: Is it actually stopping on a line of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem recently, where it was stopping on a breakpoint that no longer existed, and my Code Coverage highlighting was reflecting an older run, somehow.  Not sure why, but things were out of sync between what was current state and what it was previously.  For my instance, I was able to do a Clean Solution, then shutdown and restart VS 2010 and the problem went away.

Has only happened to me the one time, so I am not sure what I could have done to cause it.  Didn't see anything similar logged on Connect, either.

Answer (score 0):

Your debugger might be set to break when an exception is thrown.

Go to `Debug` -> `Exceptions...` -> make sure all the boxes are unchecked.

Without any more info I can't help...